# Try / Catch / Throw in CSS

Tags: html, css, exception

Is there equivalent or way to use `try{}, catch(){}, throw` in CSS, like with c++ or `try: except :` with python. I'm new to CSS and JavaScript, and I have been having lots of problems with wrong types in my CSS file, and when I insert CSS using JS. I would ideally like to have something like this:

(In my css file):

```html
<style>

  try{
     .blue{
       background-color: "blue'; /*<-- problem*/
     }
    /*Style some more stuff*/
  }catch(err){
    .blue{
      background-color: "blue"; /*<-- not a problem*/
    }
  }; 

</style>
```

Now I know that I could just set all of this stuff in JS, and use exception handling there, but for more complex stuff, it's just a lot easier to do it in plain CSS. I will do it in JS if I have to, but I rather not, so is there any syntax for doing this?

Comment: What are you using to edit your code? Any modern IDE should handle that for you. I don't see how your suggestion would really be useful anyway, since you could just as easily make a typo in the catch block.

Comment: CSS is declarative, there is no "runtime", exception handling makes no sense. If a CSS document is syntactically valid and conforms to the specification, there's no error that could happen at runtime that it would make sense to catch. Everything necessary can be checked statically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS is purely declarative, it doesn't "run." The browser simply reads through the CSS file and converts it into rules. Those rules are applied to the DOM elements by the browser. The only time you can have an "error" is a syntax error, so a try-catch wouldn't help anyway because the catch part is just as likely to have a syntax error.

Syntax errors can always be caught in advance, there's no need to catch them at runtime. You can try any of the numerous CSS validation services on the web, like the W3C's https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm really new to web stuff, so ill keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

No. But can you give an example of what you have in mind? What condition do you want to check for?

In most cases, when we blend Javascript and CSS together we do the logic in Javascript and apply classes to the relevant elements, which then have the required CSS.

For more rules-based CSS you should try [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Compass](http://compass-style.org/).